# How to prevent wifi from stopping working when Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome) goes to sleep

Tags: networking, suspend

- Distro/env: Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome)
- Laptop: Dell Precision 7510

Sometimes after my laptop resumes from screen off (I assume standby), it's still connected to wifi but in practice it's not working (not loading anything).

Also it's weird because the icon in the top bar shows "not connected" (question mark) but then when I click on it it shows "connected to..."

[image]

**How can I solve the issue so that my wifi card works properly both before and after standby? (without restarting which seems to be the only thing that works)**